# Need to filter value from string which can have dynamic number with text after that using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to filter value from string which should result me a number followed by text.
For example string looks like "There are 9 steps in the house which can be used to visit first floor".
Output :"**9 steps**".
Here number can change to any value. but that will be followed by steps

Comment: `(?<number>[0-9]+)\s*(?<text>[A-Za-z]+)` in case of "*number* followed by *text*", `(?<number>[0-9]+)\s*steps?` in case of "*number* followed by *steps*"

Answer (score -1):

you are looking for a number followed by a space and the word "steps". So

```
\d+ steps
```

is what you are looking for. `\d+` assumes that the number also may consist of several digits, like "11 steps" or "218 steps". If only one digit is allowed, then remove the "+" symbol.